# change parent directory of react appliation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, directory

I've created a simple react app using `npx create-react-app myapp` in a directoy, say, `C://user/username/myapp`. Now after fully creating the app, I felt like I should not put it at the current location due to some reason. So I've done cut/paste to location `C://user/username/NewDirectory/myapp` but than on doing `npm start` inside `myapp` directory, things got broke saying `C://user/username/myapp` not found.
However, as far as I remember, I've used relative addressing(or relative path) at every place inside `myapp`

Although I've changed it to previous location and its working again, but, ***how can I transfer `myapp` to other location without breaking anything?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `npm i` in console in new folder ;)

Comment: okk..so you mean first I've to move the folder to new directory and than need to refresh the package.json file's details using npm install, that's it ?

Comment: yeap, it's work for me, when i use window. just try, its ok for you?